# Haskell: Pathfinder through a triangle

Tags: haskell

so let's say you have a triangle:

```
triangle = ["1"
           ,"2 3"
           ,"4 5 6"]
```

This can be represented as:

```
[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I'm trying to implement a function that finds every possible path down this triangle by traversing only adjacted numbers ie 2 and 3 from 1 and 5 and 6 from 3.

For example, applied to the list of list of ints above the result would be:

```
[[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,6]]
```

so far I have a pretty poor effort:

```
findRoutes :: [[Int]]->[[Int]]
findRoutes [] = []
findRoutes (x:xs) = **find all possible paths with x as the head **:(findRoutes xs)
```

I'm really not sure how to progress, any tips guys?

Comment: Would [1,3,4] also be a solution?

Comment: @allonhadaya no since we are following this structure like a tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: All the important code is at the end.

There has to be a nice clean way of doing this with some higher order functions, so here goes:

### Plan:

- Build up the routes using `foldr`
- Put the current vertex in front of all the possible onward routes
- Cunningly use `zipWith (++)` to zip onward routes with their tail so you allow going left or right as you go down.
- Start by turning the last list of points into a list of single-point routes

**Example data**

```
example = ["11","21 22","31 32 33","41 42 43 44"]
```

Let's get that as a list of lists instead of using spaces to separate:

```
readificate :: [String] -> [[Int]]
readificate = map (map read.words)

eg = readificate example
```

so we get

```
> eg
[[11],[21,22],[31,32,33],[41,42,43,44]]
```

### Type synonyms for programmer sanity

Let's use a list of integers to represent one of the paths, so for example `[11,22,32]` would be a path. It's going to get confusing with lists of lists and we might not remember what each one means, so let's use a type synonym or two to make it clearer:

```
type Path a = [a]
type Routes a = [Path a]
```

### Make new routes by adding something at the front

I think it's easier to think of what's going on if you're part way through, rather than at the beginning or end:
If we had all the routes from `32`, namely `[ [32,42], [32,43] ]` it'd be useful to be able to put `22` at the front of all of them:

```
before :: a -> Routes a -> Routes a
a `before` rs = map (a:) rs
```

so our example gives

```
22 `before` [ [32,42], [32,43] ]
[[21,32,42],[21,32,43]]
```

That feels good, partly because `(:)` is usually much more efficient than `!!` and we can use it to build up a solution. We'll need to use the paths from `33` as well as the paths from `32` - in general we'll be able to go to two places, and we want to include both options. We can just join those together using `++`, then pop `22` infront of the combination.

### Zip the routes with their tail

When you need to do things with adjacent elements in a list, a neat trick you can reuse is to zip the list with its tail. For example `zip [1,2,3] (tail [1,2,3]) = [(1,2),(2,3)]`. `zipWith` lets you combine those, so `zipWith (+) [100,20,3] (tail [100,20,3]) = [120,23]`

We'll use that to combine a list of start points with a list of routes you could continue on for each start point. If you don't have any routes to go on from, you just have the start points as a route themselves

```
combine :: [a] -> [Routes a] -> [Routes a]
combine starts [] = map (\a -> [[a]]) starts
combine starts routes = zipWith before starts (zipWith (++) routes (tail routes))
```

### Use `foldr` to build up all the paths

Lastly we can iterate back from the end of the list using `foldr`. Since there's only one vertex at the top, there's only one list of Paths, so let's use `head` to get it.

```
findRoutes :: [[a]] -> Routes a
findRoutes = head.foldr combine []
```

so you get

```
> findRoutes eg
[[11,21,31,41],[11,21,31,42],[11,21,32,42],[11,21,32,43],[11,22,32,42],[11,22,32,43],[11,22,33,43],[11,22,33,44]]
```

## All the important code in one place

```
type Path a = [a]
type Routes a = [Path a]

before :: a -> Routes a -> Routes a
a `before` rs = map (a:) rs

combine :: [a] -> [Routes a] -> [Routes a]
combine starts [] = map (\a -> [[a]]) starts
combine starts routes = zipWith before starts (zipWith (++) routes (tail routes))

findRoutes :: [[a]] -> Routes a
findRoutes = head.foldr combine []
```

Comment: I felt the need to write this because I have an aversion to `last` and `!!` - two of my least favourite functions.

Comment: +1, you are the king dude! Perfect code and well explained. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This function can be useful in solving this:

```
getNext::[a]->[[a]]
getNext indices = [indices ++ [last indices], indices ++ [last indices+1]]
```

It returns the (N+1)th trail of indices of elements in each list, given the Nth.  For instance, if you start with the tip of the pyramid, you can get the paths into the second tier....

```
getNext [0]
```

yields

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1]]
```

Of course you then have to pull out the elements from each tier (which can be done easily using zip and (!!)....  I will leave this to you as an excercise).

What you really want to do is iterate this over each tier....  You can write a function to do this, but if you lookup the array monad, you will quickly realize that the >>= operator will do this for you

```
getNext [0] >>= getNext
```

yields

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

You can clean this up a bit

```
[[0]] >>= getNext >>= getNext
```

or

```
(>>= getNext) $ (>>= getNext) [[0]]
```

so the Nth tier path can be obtained by applying (>>= getNext) N times.  The function "iterate f x" returns an infinite list of N applications of f on x, where N is the position in the list (ie- iterate f x = [x, f x, f (f x), f (f (f x)),....]), so this is what you want.

```
getTiers n = (iterate (>>= getNext) [[0]]) !! n
```

Comment: Your indices function doesn't compile. Are those spelling mistakes deliberate?

Comment: Nope, they were just typos! :)  I've fixed it.